# В чём заключается различие реализации сервера на qt в windows и linux?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, клиент-сервер

В чём заключается различие реализации сервера на qt в windows и linux? У меня есть проект (игра) на qt (версия 5.12) где реализовано клиент-серверное взаимодействие и всё работает правильно на windows, НО когда я запускаю проект в Ubuntu 18.04.2 клиент никак не хочет подключатся к серверу, с портом ошибок не возникает

Server:

```
#include "server.h"
#include <QtNetwork>

Server::Server() {
}

void Server::startServer()
{
  if (this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 7755))
    {
      qDebug() << "Listening";
    }
  else
    {
      qDebug() << "Not listening";
    }
}

void Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
  ++clients;
  if(clients == 1) {
      sock1 = new QTcpSocket;
      sock1->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
      connect(sock1, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(socketDisconnect()));
      sockDesc1 = socketDescriptor;
      qDebug() << "player one " << socketDescriptor << " connected, waiting player two";
    }
  else if(clients == 2) {
      clients = 0;
      sockDesc2 = socketDescriptor;
      thread = new QSocketThread(sockDesc1, sockDesc2);
      connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
      thread->start();
      qDebug() << "player two " << socketDescriptor << " connected";
    }
}

void Server::socketDisconnect()
{
  qDebug() << "player one disconnected";
  --clients;
}
```

Client:

```
void Widget::startGame()
{
  delete mainMenu;
  wait = new waitingWindow;
  cellField = new CellField;
  connect(cellField, SIGNAL(endWait()), this, SLOT(endWait()));
  connect(cellField, SIGNAL(endWin()), this, SLOT(endGameWin()));
  connect(cellField, SIGNAL(endLose()), this, SLOT(endGameLose()));
  connect(cellField, SIGNAL(endDraw()), this, SLOT(endGameDraw()));
  cellField->socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
  cellField->socket->connectToHost("мой ip(дабы не палить:D)", 7755);
  connect(cellField->socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), cellField, SLOT(socketReady()));
  connect(cellField->socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), cellField, SLOT(socketDisconnect()));
  layout->addWidget(wait);
  setLayout(layout);
}
```

Comment: По-сути, с точки зрения Qt, ни в чем. Порт может быть занят?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите фаервол:

```
sudo nft list ruleset
```

и

```
sudo iptables-save
```

В новых дистрах блокируется все подряд..

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ошибку, дело в том что в функцию `incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)` нужно передавать дескриптор используя тип данных `qintptr`!

Вот так: `incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`